# DNS resolution of Pubilc registered FQDN to internal IP

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dns-zone

Let´s assume i have a hostname app1.example.com. It´s registered in public DNS. Now I have a private DNS Zone called example.internal. I add an Host A entry for app1.example.com with an internal IP as the destination.

Now i want that my internal clients resolve app1.example.com to the internal IP. The DNS suffix is added to the connection. Can this work if a client tries to resolve this or will the query always be resolved to the Public IP if i don´t specify a DNS suffix?

Comment: What you want is a split horizon DNS, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do, is have a DNS zone configured on your internal DNS server for example.com, which points app1.example.com to the internal IP address of the system providing your service. At your external DNS hosting provider, you will need to create an A record to point app1.example.com to your external IP address.

Your internal domain example.internal would not have any effect on resolution of records in the example.com zone, neither would the DNS suffix of the connection. You don’t need to add a DNS suffix to the network interface in order for the computer to resolve hostnames, as long as you’re referencing the full host name.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this task go ahead and create A record in local dns mapping app1.example.com to domain name if need you can even create reverse lookup record as well . So when ever your access this domain in internal LAN to triggers recercive querry and dns traffic reaches to internal local dns and it's resolve to app1  example.com to internal private ip address of server

In same way if you wants to access app1.example.com from internet or any other networks   create A record in authoritative dns of your organization mapping with public IP address of server with app1.example.com